# How to retrieve SQL Error message with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, exception

I have developed a small application accessing a PostgreSQL database with Hibernate. When I try to delete a record involved in a foreign key with another table, a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` is caught with the message:

> Could not execute statement

But I noticed in the console window that there is a more detailed message as follows:

```
13:13:49,222 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) ERROR: update or delete on table "AdminSite" violates foreign key constraint "FK_AdminUserSite" on table "AdminUserProfile"
  Detail: Key (STCode)=(HO        ) is still referenced from the table "AdminUserProfile".
```

How to retrieve this message which is more meaningful?

Comment: I'm confused too, what do you mean by 'retrieve'? You clearly have access to the logging. If you mean how to get it as part of an exception chain, you likely can't. This kind of detail logging has the potential to bleed out to the outside world if it would be part of the exception chain and that is a security incident.

Comment: It is certainly a nested exception (look at the fields of your exception, you'll see a "cause" for example)

Comment: I want to give a better feedback to the user so that proper action is taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hibernate wraps SQLExceptions thrown while interacting with the database in a JDBCException. In fact, Hibernate will attempt to convert the exception into a more meningful subclass of JDBCException. **The underlying SQLException is always available via JDBCException.getCause()**.

Hibernate documentation specifies the above and is available under [hibernate documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/transactions-demarcation-exceptions.html).